# Написание плагина Flutter с использованием сторонней SDK

Tags: flutter, jar, плагин, aar

Пытаюсь понять принцип написания плагинов с использованием сторонней SDK, но не понимаю. Исходные данные следующие:
есть SDK в виде jar- и aar-файлов и документации с описанием java-интерфейса. Надо написать плагин с использованием этой SDK. У каждого файла есть java-интерфейс с 4 методами (пусть будут называться methode_01 - methode_04).
Я пытаюсь понять, как я должен подключить SDK и как вызывать эти 4 метода.
Из [вопроса на англоязычной SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73724659/how-to-import-aar-file-in-the-flutter-plugin) я понял, как я могу подключить сам aar-файл к проекту - просто копирую файл в папка_плагина/Android/app/lib
далее, мне надо прописать зависимости от этого файла в Android/app/build.gradle
Но тут возникает первый вопрос: я не понимаю, надо это прописывать в блоке buildscript в самом начале файла (там тоже есть подблок зависимостей), или же я должен просто в конце build.gradle вставить следующий блок?

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'lib')
   implementation files('lib/myaarlibr.aar')
}
```

Второй вопрос: как я должен создать каннал, где будет работать myaarlibr.aar и откуда я буду вызывать методы из java-интерфейса этого самого aar-файла? Т.е. прочитав документацию, я понимаю, что я должен:

В /lib/plugin.dart отредактировать дарт-файл. В нём я буду обращаться к каналу, где и запущен aar-файл. Там я должен написать дарт-интерфейсы для всех 4 методов, которые планирую вызывать. Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
class FlutterPlugin {
 static const MethodChannel _channel =
     const MethodChannel('flutter_plugin');
 
 static Future methode_01(Argument_type argument) async {
   await _channel.invokeMethod('methode_01', {'argument': argument});
 }
}
```

В android/src/main/kotlin/com/example/plugin/plugin.kt должен отредактировать котлин-файл. При создании проекта тут размещён шаблонный код:

```
public class FlutterPluginPlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
 private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel

 companion object {
   @JvmStatic
   fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
     val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "flutter_Plugin")
     channel.setMethodCallHandler(FlutterPluginPlugin())
   }
 }

 override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
   channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "flutter_Plugin")
   channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
 }

 override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
   if (call.method == "getPlatformVersion") {
     result.success("Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}")
   } else {
     result.notImplemented()
   }
 }

 override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
   channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
 }
}
```

я понимаю, что методы registerWith() и onAttachedToEngine() делают одно и то же, и как раз создают канал с файлом, откуда я вызываю методы. Но я не понимаю, как я должен описывать aar-файл, чтобы открыть его здесь.